# Sobolev space is spanned by distributions supported on half-lines?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Could anyone help me prove the following basic statement about Sobolev spaces:
For any $s \leq 1/2$,
$$H^s(\mathbb{R}) = H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$$
where $H^s_-(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the subspace of $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ supported on $(-\infty, 0]$ and $H^s_+(\mathbb{R}) = \{u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}) \mid \operatorname{supp} u \subset [0,\infty)\}$.

I am only really interested in the case $s < 1/2$, but the result should be true for $s=1/2$.

**Context**

This question stems from my attempt to prove subjectivity of the natural map
$$H^s_+(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^s([0,\infty)) = H^s(\mathbb{R}) / H^s_-(\mathbb{R}),$$
and its higher dimensional analogues $H^s_+(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow H^s([0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^d)$.
This property is claimed in Melrose's [notes](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erbm/daomwc3.ps), Proposition 3.5.1, with different notations: $\dot{\mathcal{H}}^s(X) = H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{H}^s(X) = H^s([0,\infty))$.
The proof involves taking the dual of the injection $H^{-s}_+(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^{-s}([0,\infty))$.
But this requires the natural topology of $H^{-s}_+(\mathbb{R})$ to coincide with the subspace topology from $H^{-s}([0,\infty))$, which is not justified in the notes.
I believe the latter property is equivalent to $H^{-s}_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^{-s}_+(\mathbb{R})$ being closed in $H^{-s}(\mathbb{R})$.

**My thoughts**

In the case $s < 1/2$, I can show that $H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$ contains the Schwartz functions $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, but this does not imply the desired result unless $H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$ is closed.

The inclusion $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \subset H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) + H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$ is obtained by multiplying $u \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ by sequences of smooth functions approximating the indicators on $(\infty, 0]$ and $[0, \infty)$, and showing that the resulting sequences converge in $H^s$.
For example, fixing a smooth $\phi$ supported on $[0,\infty)$ and eventually equal to $1$, then consider its scalings $\phi_{\epsilon}(x) = \phi(x/\epsilon)$.
One can show that $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} u \phi_{\epsilon}$ converges in $H^s$, $s \in [0,1/2)$ using
the inequality $\|v\|_{H^s} \lesssim \|v\|_{H^0}^{1-s} \|v\|_{H^1}^{s}$ and the crude estimates
$$\|u(\phi_{\epsilon} - \phi_{\delta})\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{L^\infty} \|\phi_{\epsilon} - \phi_{\delta}\|_{L^\infty} \|\phi_{\epsilon} - \phi_{\delta}\|_{L^0}^{1/2} \lesssim \epsilon^{1/2}$$
$$\|u \cdot \partial (\phi_{\epsilon} - \phi_{\delta})\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{L^\infty} \|\partial (\phi_{\epsilon} - \phi_{\delta})\|_{L^\infty} \|\partial (\phi_{\epsilon} - \phi_{\delta})\|_{L^0}^{1/2} \lesssim \epsilon^{-1} \epsilon^{1/2}$$
I am unable to generalize this to the case $u \in H^s$ or $s = 1/2$.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you argue by density now? You have the inclusion from the Schwartz space into that sum. If the inclusion is continuous, then it extends uniquely to a map from $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ into that sum.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Mason. The problem is that I don't think the map $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^s_-(\mathbb{R}) \oplus H^s_+(\mathbb{R})$ I have constructed is continuous when $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is given the $H^s$-topology. I have to use $\|u\|_{W^{1,\infty}} < \infty$ to prove convergence of the sequences. Everything would work if there is a bound $\|u\phi_{\epsilon}\|_{H^s} \lesssim \|u\|_{H^s}$ uniform in $\epsilon$ and $u$. But I failed to prove such a bound.

Comment: I have moved this question to [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429233/sobolev-space-is-spanned-by-distributions-supported-on-half-lines/429288?noredirect=1#comment1104536_429288).